# php ldap operational attributes

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'd be surprised if this hasn't been asked a million times but I've yet to find a solution.

I am listing Active Directory users using PHPs "ldap_search" and would like to display certain "operational attributes" such as the date the user was created (createTimeStamp) using the following method:

```
$filter = "CN=*";
$result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
```

This works and I get a list of users, however **createTimeStamp** isn't returned. I have read that this is because it is classed as an "operational attribute" which aren't part of the normal result set. Apparently these attributes will only be returned if they are specifically requested. So I then tried this:

```
$filter = "CN=*";
$attr = array("samaccountname","createTimeStamp");
$result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
```

This still does not return a value for **createTimeStamp**. So my question is this: is it likely that Active Directory is in some way configured to not return these values, and if so, can this be changed?

---

**EDIT**: If it helps we can retrieve **lastLogon** which is in *Large Integer/Interval* format but not **createTimeStamp** which is in *UTC Coded Time* format; I'm not sure how relevant this is as the problem we are having is that the data is not being returned at all.

---

**EDIT 2**: I have used LDIFDE (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237677) to search Active Directory using this line:

```
ldifde -f ldaptest.txt -s myServer -d "DC=domain,DC=com" -p subtree -r "(sAMAccountName=*BWayne*)" -l "createTimeStamp"
```

...and it returns this:

```
dn: CN=Wayne Bruce,OU=Section....
changetype: add
createTimeStamp: 20100406101951.0Z
```

So if it is an access issue then it only seems to be affecting the PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Entries and attributes can be protected by access controls. Use a known good tool to attempt to retrieve `createTimestamp` to determine if access controls are in place. Try this on an entry whch is known to have the `createTimestamp` attribute and on your test entry:

```
ldapsearch -h hostname -p port -D bindDN -w bindPassword \
    -b baseObject -s base '(&)' createTimestamp
```

Be sure to use the same DN to authenticate the tests in each case.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have to admit I'm a bit new to LDAP and I'm not familiar with **ldapsearch** - I am using Windows Server 2000 R2 and there doesn't seem to be any such command line function. I ran the utility *ldp.exe* (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224543) on the server in question and it returns the desired operational attributes.

Comment: I have used LDIFDE (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237677) to search Active Directory using this line: `ldifde -f ldaptest.txt -s myServer -d
"DC=domain,DC=com" -p subtree -r "(sAMAccountName=*BWayne*)" -l "createTimeStamp"` and it returns this: `dn: CN=Wayne Bruce,OU=Section....
changetype: add
createTimeStamp: 20100406101951.0Z` so if it *is* an access issue then it only seems to be affecting the PHP script

Comment: When you tested with LDIFDE, did you authenticate the connection with the same DN as your PHP script?

Comment: No, good point! I've just run it again adding `-b username domain password` to the end of the command and got the same result (success).

Comment: Correction, I am using "username" for LDIFDE while I am using "username@domain.com" for PHP. I can't use the "username" format in PHP or the "username@domain.com" format with LDIFDE without getting an error.

Comment: This result generally means an access control is restricting access to operational attributes. This will often be the case, since LDAP clients must *not* rely on the names, OIDs, or values of operational attributes.

Comment: Do you you mean you *are* using the same authentication state (username or DN or whatever)?

Comment: No, I mean I'm using the same user account, but the PHP script only works if it is in the format "username@domain.com" while LDIFDE doesn't like this so I am dropping the "@domain.com" when testing in LDIFDE.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38549/discussion-between-terry-gardner-and-valoukh)